# how to databind the datagrid Mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Kinda stuck on this mvvm binding the datagrid with my viewmodel im making a ObservableCollection and then pass the dummy data into the gridview but im not sure how to do it I started doing it without mvvm and had no problem now im kinda stuck and unsure how to do it

this is my View - UserView.xaml

```
Grid>
      
        <DataGrid x:Name="dt_Users" ItemsSource="{Binding UserItems}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="161,222,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="585"   />
        
    
    </Grid>
```

My viewmodel - userviewmodel.cs

```
public class UserViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        ObservableCollection<User> UserItems = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        
        private void fetchgrid()
        {
            UserItems.Add(new User { firstname = "h", lastname = "h" });
            UserItems.Add(new User { firstname = "h", lastname = "h" });
        }


}
```

and my model - user.cs

```
 public class User
    {
        public string firstname { get; set; }

        public string lastname { get; set; }

       
    }
```

what am I overseeing?

Comment: Where do you create `UserViewModel` instance and assign it as `DataContext` to a view? See [this tutorial](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/#:~:text=the%20ProductModel%20DataTemplate.-,Starting%20the%20Sample,-And%20finally%2C%20to).

Comment: I have no idea how to do it 
I was just trying

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to assign an instance of `UserViewModel` to the `DataContext` of your view.

Either in XAML, for example:

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <UserViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>
  
  <Grid>
   <DataGrid ... />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

or in code-behind, for example in the constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  this.DataContext = new UserViewModel();
}
```

Alternatively define the instance of the view model in App.xaml and use `{StaticResource}` to set the `DataContext` in XAML.

There are many ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind to *public properties* so the first thing to do is to change the `UserItems` field into a property in the view model:

```
public class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<User> UserItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<User>();
    ...
}
```

Then you also need to set the `DataContext` of the view to an instance of your view model class. The easiest way to do this is to add the following line to the constructor of the view in `UserView.xaml.cs`:

```
public UserView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new UserViewModel(); //<-- add this
}
```